# getting 404 from a route with a param - express 4

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Im trying to use a param in a route... tried the 4.x docs on express website but no use.. im still getting 404... seems like its not hitting my function..

The other routes to create and list all itens are fine..

```
var db = require('../db');

var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
var Users = mongoose.model( 'Users' );
var app = express.Router();



//PARAM
app.param('name', function(req, res, next, name) {
    Users.find({name:name}, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        else if (!name) {
            return next(new Error('failed to load user'));
        }

        req.user = docs[0];
        next(); 
    });
});

//SHOW
app.get('/users/:name', function(req,res){
    res.render('users/profile', {user: req.user});
});
```

tried a simple version... same 404... (btw the name exist.. it shows on the list item)

```
//SHOW
    app.get('/users/:name', function(req, res, name){
    var name = req.param('name');
    Users.find({name: name}, function(err, docs) {  
        req.user = docs[0];
        next(); 
    }); 
res.render('users/profile', {user: req.user});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using an Express 4 Router like it's an Express 3 app. A Router lets you set up a collection of related routes, like you have done. However, you then must attach the Router to your larger Express server.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

// attach some things to router
// router.get('/users/:name', ...)

app.use('/foo', router);
```

Would mount all the paths that `router` handles under the `/foo` path, like `/foo/users/:name`.

Comment: im using this to call on my app.js --> app.use('/users', require('./routes/users').users);

Comment: im such a noob... thanks.. the thing is.. i already use the app.use to set a root router.. but i was putting /users/:name ... should use just /:name